# create a field, by many to many relationship on ef core (razor pages)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, razor-pages

i want to create a field, by many to many relationship on ef core, this is my book class:

```
 public class Book:BaseModel
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Author { get; private set; }
        public List<BookCategory> Categories { get; private set; }
        public Book(string name, string author)
        {
            Name = name;
            Author = author;
            Categories=new List<BookCategory>();
        }
        public Book()
        {
        }
    }
```

and the category class:

```
public class Category:BaseModel
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public List<BookCategory> Books { get; private set; }
        
        public Category(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            Books = new List<BookCategory>();
        }
        public Category()
        {
        }
```

my bookCategory class:

```
    public class BookCategory
    {
        public long BookId { get; set; }
        public long CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

and now when i am creating a new book, i want to select multiple items of category and save this items to the categories property in the book:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="?" class="control-label">Category product</label>
                    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" asp-for="?"
                            asp-items='new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name")' >
                        <option value="0">productCategory</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="error"></span>
                </div>
```

this is my repository(just i show here my Categoryrepository, the BookRepository is like this):
(notice: because of my architucture i use CategoryViewModel and BookViewModel instead of Book and Category,

```
public List<CategoryViewModel> GetAllCategories()
        {
            return _shopContext.Categories
                .Include(x => x.Books)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Book)
                .Select(x => new CategoryViewModel
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    //Books = ?
                }).ToList();
   
        
        }
```

CreateBook Class:

```
public long Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
```

Index Model:

```
 public IActionResult OnGetCreate()
        {
            
            var book = new CreateBook()
            {
                Categories = _categoryApplication.GetAllCategories(),
            };
            return Partial("Create" , book);
        }

        public JsonResult OnPostCreate(CreateBook command)
        {

            var book = _bookApplication.Create(command);
            return new JsonResult(book);
        }
```

it show me the categories, but when i select the items and push submit, the categories send null,
maybe because i didn't defenited category id in the book class,it's because of using many to many relationship that u should definete category id in a seperate class,and now what should i do?
i use from ? in some lines, it means that i don't know what should i use instead ,

i am using many to many relationship on ef core, i want to create a book with a list of categories, i can see the categories but when i select them and push submit button the categoreies sent as null,

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is impossible to receive the value for you use `private` access modifier.

Secondly, the multiple select listpdownwill match the type of `List<int>` or `int[]`.

At last, Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.

The whole working demo for how to receive the multiple select dropdown should be:

Model:

```
public class Book : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get;  set; }
    public string Author { get;  set; }
    public List<BookCategory> Categories { get;  set; }
    public Book(string name, string author)
    {
        Name = name;
        Author = author;
        Categories = new List<BookCategory>();
    }
    public Book()
    {

    }
}
public class Category : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<BookCategory> Books { get; private set; }

    public Category(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Books = new List<BookCategory>();
    }
    public Category()
    {

    }
}
public class BookCategory
{
    public long BookId { get; set; }
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Book.Name" class="control-label">گروه محصول</label>
        <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" asp-for="CategoryIds"
                asp-items='new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name")'>
            <option value="0">گروه محصول</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Book.Name" class="error"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Book.Author" class="control-label">گروه محصول</label>
        <input asp-for="Book.Author" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Book.Author" class="error"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int[] CategoryIds { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {            
        Categories = ......
    }
    public void OnPost()
    {
        //append the value to the Book model
        foreach(int id in CategoryIds)
        {
            Book.Categories = new List<BookCategory>();
            Book.Categories.Add(new BookCategory() { BookId = Book.Id, CategoryId = id });
        }
         //do your stuff for database insert operation...
    }

}
```

Comment: it dosn't work, i have updated my codes, plz take a look at it again, maybe u can help me